# HTACCESS: Redirect only .php without jquery string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to change it so that it does not throw 404 error when php has a query string, eg: `test.php?lang=en`

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

If it contains the query string, just to remove the `.php` extension without redirect to 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is .php and without query_string 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\.php\s
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: This redirect all .php to 404 error. I need avoid this rule if .php has query string for example: .php?lang=en. If query string exist so dont apply this rule on .php file